# Accessing SVG element attribute from <use> element through external file

Tags: javascript, svg

I have a svg line defined in line.svg file like so:

```
<line id="vertical_line" x1="357.5" y1="153" x2="357.5" y2="80"/>
```

I am referencing "vertical_line" in javascript and adding the svg line to the DOM.

```
var verticalLine = document.createElementNS('http://www.w3.org/2000/svg', 'use');
verticalLine.setAttributeNS('http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink', 'xlink:href','./images/line.svg#vertical_line');
```

I want to be able to manipulate verticalLine's "y1" attribute value. But I cannot access that attribute via the verticalLine object.

What method can I use to access svg attribute of the original SVG element when creating the element through javascript from an external file?

Comment: Don't think you can do it. Perhaps when shadow DOM becomes more standardised/implemented this will be available.

Comment: I am able to get this to work by including it inline, it is only when I reference it through external file that this fails. This makes it difficult to organize numerous svg files.